# Changing the colour of the tk.optionmenu widget

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, optionmenu

I use this command to create a tk.optionmenu widget but its a grey colour and I want it to be white.

```
optionmenu = tk.OptionMenu(root,variable,*(variables)).place(x=375, y=175)
```

How do I change it to the white colour? I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

```
optionmenu = tk.OptionMenu(root,variable,*(variables)colour="White").place(x=375, y=175)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the background color by doing the following:

```
optionmenu['menu'].config(bg='red')
```

Or whatever color you want. You can find a list of colors [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/37701)

You can inspect further keyword arguements you can configure by doing the following:

```
print(optionmenu['menu'].keys())
```

Which will return:

```
['activebackground', 'activeborderwidth', 'activeforeground', 'background', 'bd', 'bg', 
 'borderwidth', 'cursor', 'disabledforeground', 'fg', 'font', 'foreground', 'postcommand', 
 'relief', 'selectcolor', 'takefocus', 'tearoff', 'tearoffcommand', 'title', 'type']
```